`matplotlib` figure border and text disagree about the figure limits
I find the behavior of the following image to be surprising.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.text(1.3, 1.3, "ABC", color = 'red')

# Add blue border
#
fig.patch.set_linewidth(3)
fig.patch.set_edgecolor("blue")

fig.text(0, 1, "DEF", color = 'red')

plt.show()
plt.close()
fig.patch.set_linewidth(3)
fig.patch.set_edgecolor("blue")

fig.text(0, 1, "DEF")

plt.show()
plt.close()


When I use plt.text to add text to the figure beyond the upper limit of 1, the border expands to contain that text in the top right.
The border comes from a fig method, seemingly using the new bounds of the figure to determine border placement.
However, the fig.text line, another fig method, puts the text at the original upper limit, what would have been the upper limit if I had not used the plt.text line.
Why do these disagree when they come from methods on the same figure object, and how can I get the fig.text line to automatically consider the additional text?

plt.text wraps ax.text, so your "ABC" is placed in data coordinates, whereas for fig.text you are placing at top left of the figure, as you say.

@RuthC Yes, but fig knows its real(?) extent when it comes to drawing the border.

@gboffi you are right, I misunderstood the question

@RuthC Further thinking. The first text changes fig.patch but not the Figure coordinates, the top border of the Axes is still at 0.8 in figure coordinates, now I can see why the Figure coordinates have not changed!

And it's the patch that draws the border, not the figure itself…

@gboffi Then is there a way to place the text in patch coordinates?

If  Patch'es have a method to do it... I guess that you can however place fig.text beyond the 0-1, 0-1 original boundaries. Just try…

@gboffi fig.text(0, 1.3, "DEF", color = 'red') places the text too high. What would be great is a method, somewhere, that automatically figured out how high the rest of the figure is and places text there, same as the border methods figure out how big the border is.

the axes coordinates are referred to the subplot's frame boundaries, 1.3 in axes coordinates is somehow smaller on the canvas than 1.3 in figure coordinate. An accurate placement requires, I guess , Matplotlib Transforms, of which I don't know enough, sorry
